# How to avoid videos (made of images) look tilted in VLC?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, vlc-media-player

I created [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6m2waj0svvc70i/out.mp4?dl=0) using the following *FFmpeg* command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.ffconcat -c:v libx264  -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 out.mp4
```

The content of the file *in.ffconcat* is:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file caption_01.png
duration 4
file caption_01.png
duration 2
file caption_02.png
duration 5
file caption_03.png
```

I can play the video perfectly using Windows Media Player and Chrome, but using VLC player the images look tilted like [image]

Why is that?

Comment: I believe you may have rotation set in your player. `Window` > `Video Effects` > `Geometry` > Uncheck `Transform`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LordNeckbeard that was the problem! I saw the *rotate clock* and thought it wasn't rotated at all but after clear the *rotate checkbox*, it move a little ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may have rotation set in VLC:
[image: VLC Adjustment and Effects]

To clear it go to:

`Tools` → `Effects and Filters` → `Video Effects` → `Geometry` → Uncheck `Rotate`

Some versions may be different, such as:

`Window` → `Video Effects` → `Geometry` → Uncheck `Rotate`

Comment: As I said, the *rotate checkbox" was what I cleared to fix the problem. Thanks anyway for your reply. If you edit it, I will select this reply as the correct/accepted answer.

Comment: @gsc-frank Updated. I used Transform recently so it was in my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to rotate back to normal using the mouse cursor, it rotates too much. Click and hold the left mouse button on the rotate wheel and use the left or right cursor control arrows on the keyboard for greater control.